How to get the first and last record on SSIS?
I have a flat file with date information like this.
Date
09/08/2019
10/08/2019
26/07/2020
26/07/2020
...
26/07/2020

enter image description here
I would like to read the first record year 2019 and save under Season Year '2019'. and the first record 09/08/2019 as Season First Date and the last record 26/07/2020 as Season Last Date. So on SSIS I designed as follows.
enter image description here
Flat file -> Data conversion (for some reason it reads date as string so I changed it to date [DTDATE] as 'ConvertedDate'
YEAR(ConvertedDate)

-> Sort Ascending -> Multicast -> 1. Derived Column to get the season year by YEAR(ConvertedDate), -> 2. Aggregate Operation Minimum -> Derived Column
(RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",FirstDate),2) + "/" + RIGHT("0"+ (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",FirstDate),2) + "/" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",FirstDate))

-> Data Conversion to DTDATE -> 3. Aggregate Operation Maximum -> Derived Column *
[RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",LastDate),2) + "/" + RIGHT("0" +
(DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",LastDate),2) + "/" +
(DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",LastDate)*]

-> Union All -> OLEDB Destination.
But I am stuck at Union ALL. I am not sure I to configure Union All. It seems like there is an issue with Data Type. Could you please guide me what went wrong here? I have five flat files to do the same job. My destination attributes are Season_Year int not null, Season_Start date not null, Seaason_end date not null.
Row Number Transformation and Random Sampling Method are not available on my version.
enter image description here
Thank you in advance.

I think the easiest way would be to import the entire file into a temp/staging table and then just select it from there.  or you could write your own C# script task to do it.

Could you elaborate little bit more on temp/staging table? Thank you!

You create a table inside SQL server that you will use to import the file into.  Then import the file into the table using SSIS.  Then you can select the first/last record from there.

@Brad Thank you I got it sorted using the staging table!!
